# GTK+3 compile error "Could not find signal handler `` Did you compile with -rdynamic?

Tags: c++, gtk3

I am making a GUI with Glade and GTK+3. I have followed many tutorials, read many forum posts but still I can get rid of "Gtk-WARNING **: 14:50:06.794: Could not find signal handler 'on_window_main_destroy'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?" warnings for each signal I have. Please help. This problem is really killing me!

I have made a simple GUI in Glade. It consists of main window, fixed grid, two scales and two adjustments connected to the scales. I have connected signals to main window "destroy" "on_window_main_destroy" and the adjustments "value changed -> on_adjustment_scale_exposure_value_changed" and "value changed -> on_adjustment_scale_gain_value_changed".

Then I have written the code using geany. Whatever I try, every time I run the program I get the above error messages for all signals.

In Glade I have tried with plain save ass and save ass "builder" file. No difference.

I have tried with many different g++ and gcc commands and no difference.

Glade code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_scale_exposure">
    <property name="lower">1</property>
    <property name="upper">1000</property>
    <property name="value">10</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
    <signal name="value-changed" handler="on_adjustment_scale_exposure_value_changed" swapped="no"/>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_scale_gain">
    <property name="lower">1</property>
    <property name="upper">20</property>
    <property name="value">1</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
    <signal name="value-changed" handler="on_adjustment_scale_gain_value_changed" swapped="no"/>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_main">
    <property name="width_request">1024</property>
    <property name="height_request">600</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="border_width">5</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_main_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScale" id="scale_exposure">
            <property name="width_request">30</property>
            <property name="height_request">600</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <property name="adjustment">adjustment_scale_exposure</property>
            <property name="inverted">True</property>
            <property name="round_digits">1</property>
            <property name="digits">0</property>
            <property name="value_pos">bottom</property>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScale" id="scale_gain">
            <property name="width_request">30</property>
            <property name="height_request">600</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <property name="adjustment">adjustment_scale_gain</property>
            <property name="inverted">True</property>
            <property name="round_digits">1</property>
            <property name="value_pos">bottom</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">30</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Written code:

```cpp
#include "gtk/gtk.h"

GtkWidget *g_scale_exposure;
GtkAdjustment *g_adjustment_scale_exposure;
GtkWidget *g_scale_gain;
GtkAdjustment *g_adjustment_scale_gain;
GtkWidget *g_lbl_exposure;
GtkWidget *g_lbl_gain;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "main.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_scale_exposure = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "scale_exposure"));
    g_scale_gain = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "scale_gain"));
    g_adjustment_scale_exposure = GTK_ADJUSTMENT(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "adjustment_scale_exposure"));
    g_adjustment_scale_gain = GTK_ADJUSTMENT(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "adjustment_scale_gain"));
    g_lbl_exposure = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lbl_exposure"));
    g_lbl_gain = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lbl_gain"));

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

void on_window_main_destroy(){
    gtk_main_quit();
}

void on_adjustment_scale_exposure_value_changed(GtkAdjustment *adjustment_scale_exposure, gpointer data){
    int scaleValue = gtk_adjustment_get_value(GTK_ADJUSTMENT(g_adjustment_scale_exposure));

    printf("moi, %d\n", scaleValue);

}

void on_adjustment_scale_gain_value_changed(GtkAdjustment *adjustment_scale_gain, gpointer data){
    float scaleValue = gtk_adjustment_get_value(GTK_ADJUSTMENT(g_adjustment_scale_gain));
    printf("moi2, %f\n", scaleValue);

}
```

g++ code:

```
g++ -rdynamic -Wall  normiApiTestiGlade2.cpp -o runme `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0`
```

Expected result would be to run the GUI with signals connected. Now the GUI starts and I can move the sliders but nothing is changed (except in the gui).

The warnings:
(runme:18098): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:09:26.660: Could not find signal handler 'on_window_main_destroy'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

(runme:18098): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:09:26.660: Could not find signal handler 'on_adjustment_scale_gain_value_changed'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

(runme:18098): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:09:26.660: Could not find signal handler 'on_adjustment_scale_exposure_value_changed'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04, Glade 3.22.1, GTK+3

Comment: The error message clearly asks "Did you compile with -rdynamic?" And the compiler command line you posted clearly shows that you *do*. So, have you tried *not* doing that?

Comment: Yes I have tried without -rdynamic. Same result

Answer (score 1):

[gtk_builder_connect_signals](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-connect-signals) has all the information you need.

> In the case that symbols are not explicitly added; **it uses GModule**’s introspective features ... to look at the application’s symbol table...
>
> **If you rely on GModule** support to lookup callbacks in the symbol table, the following details should be noted:
>
> When compiling applications for Windows, you must declare signal callbacks with G_MODULE_EXPORT, or they will not be put in the symbol table. On Linux and Unices, this is not necessary; applications should instead be compiled with the -Wl,--export-dynamic CFLAGS, and linked against gmodule-export-2.0.

You must pass `-Wl,--export-dynamic` (sic) to compiler.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, although I do not really understand. Where in the g++ line should --export-dynamic and -Wl be inserted?

By the way, I got the program working by calling g_signal_connect for every signal. Still I get the original error but the signals work.

Comment: @Dan `gcc so.c -Wl,--export-dynamic  \`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0\` && ./a.out` that's how I compiled thigs.

Comment: Same result with your gcc line. Iḿ starting to thing that this is a Glade problem. But have no idea why...